# how to fill big holes in blender

Tags: modifiers, faces

I have big holes in the mesh of human skull. I want to topologically fill holes. Like in the picture you can see holes. I can close them with face>fill option but not grid fill. It gives the error  of that "select two edges loop or a single closed edge loop which two edge loops can be calculated"

[image]

Comment: you could select all and try an Alt F but I'm not sure it will work

Comment: Yeah this is not something that's super simple to fix by itself. There are entire jobs dedicated to cleaning up meshes made from 3D Scans. Usually this kind of thing can be better solved in the actual scan/mesh generation process. Once you've got a mesh like this it will take a decent bit of manual work to clean it up.